# Livecycle javascript...condense if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, livecycle

I'm working on a form that will have a "Validate" button. The purpose of this button is to check and make sure all the fields are completed (this is what the project demands). Below is the code that checks to see if the field is `null` and then changes the border color and displays a text box.

```
if (form1.Main.sfRequestor.requestNameFirst.rawValue == null){
    form1.Main.sfRequest.txtValidate.presence = "visible";
    form1.Main.sfRequestor.requestNameFirst.border.edge.color.value = "255,0,0"
} else {
    form1.Main.sfRequest.txtValidate.presence = "hidden";
    form1.Main.sfRequestor.requestNameFirst.border.edge.color.value = "255,255,255"
};

if (form1.Main.sfRequestor.requestNameLast.rawValue == null){
    form1.Main.sfRequest.txtValidate.presence = "visible";
    form1.Main.sfRequestor.requestNameLast.border.edge.color.value = "255,0,0"
} else {
    form1.Main.sfRequest.txtValidate.presence = "hidden";
    form1.Main.sfRequestor.requestNameLast.border.edge.color.value = "255,255,255"
};
```

There are 20+ fields in several subforms that need to be checked. I'm trying to consolidate the code but am at a loss on how to do so. Can variables handle field names in Javascript?

Comment: What are the `form1`, `Main`, `sfRequestor` and other variables?

Comment: with the bracket notation you can do requestNameFirst["rawValue"]

Comment: what kind of elements do you have? Are they all textboxes?

Comment: mostly textboxes but dates, dropdowns, a table and a radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this into a loop pretty easily, and could write it as an *IIFE* to keep your namespace clean

```
(function (arr) {
    var txtValidate = form1.Main.sfRequest.txtValidate,
        i, e;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        e = form1.Main.sfRequestor[arr[i]]; // cache me
        if (e.rawValue == null){
            txtValidate.presence = "visible";
            e.border.edge.color.value = "255,0,0"
        } else {
            txtValidate.presence = "hidden";
            e.border.edge.color.value = "255,255,255"
        }
    }
}(['requestNameFirst', 'requestNameLast']));
```

However, it looks like `txtValidate.presence` only ever gets set to whatever the last item's conditions were, are you sure you don't want to use a flag and set this last instead? e.g.

```
(function (arr) {
    var txtValidateState = 'hidden',
        i, e;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        e = form1.Main.sfRequestor[arr[i]];
        if (e.rawValue == null){
            txtValidateState = "visible"; // any null makes txtValidate visible
            e.border.edge.color.value = "255,0,0"
        } else {
            e.border.edge.color.value = "255,255,255"
        }
    }
    form1.Main.sfRequest.txtValidate.presence = txtValidateState; // set last
}(['requestNameFirst', 'requestNameLast']));
```

---

Update for generic forms, assuming `sfRequestor` and `sfRequest`

```
(function (form, arr) {
    var txtValidateState = 'hidden',
        i, e;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        e = form.sfRequestor[arr[i]];
        if (e.rawValue == null){
            txtValidateState = "visible";
            e.border.edge.color.value = "255,0,0";
        } else {
            e.border.edge.color.value = "255,255,255";
        }
    }
    form.sfRequest.txtValidate.presence = txtValidateState;
}(form1.Main, ['requestNameFirst', 'requestNameLast']));
```

---

Update Assuming `sfRequest` is a constant but `sfRequestor` could be something different

```
(function () { // moved IIFE to protect namespace
    function validate(form, subform, arr) { // now named, new param subform
        var txtValidateState = 'hidden',
            i, e;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            e = form[subform][arr[i]]; // select from subform
            if (e.rawValue == null){
                txtValidateState = "visible";
                e.border.edge.color.value = "255,0,0";
            } else {
                e.border.edge.color.value = "255,255,255";
            }
        }
        form.sfRequest.txtValidate.presence = txtValidateState; // assuming stays same
    }
    validate(form1.Main, 'sfRequestor', ['requestNameFirst', 'requestNameLast']);
    validate(form1.Main, 'sfClientInfo', ['firstname']);
    // if you have many here you can re-write as a loop again
}());
```

Comment: wow, thank you! the only thing I can't see working is that there are multiple subforms.

Comment: Maybe you'd be able to do it with a simple extra param/arg to reference which form you want :)

Comment: @silviak please see edit and let me know if your forms aren't referencable this way ---- if you wanted to run this function multiple times (for different forms) you might want to give it a name now too

Comment: I tried running the updated (3rd) code block. I added another field in a different subform but it didn't work for that field. I am new to javascript and I'm trying to read your code to understand it but I can't find where the subforms would be listed

Comment: @silviak it's written to do one _form_ at a time, the last line takes the _form_, then the names of items in `sfRequestor`. If you want to do several _forms_, change this from an _IIFE_ to a named _function_, then invoke it once for each _form_. If this hasn't helped further, please give an example of a different form so I can see how the code would need to be modified.

Comment: My apologies for any confusion. Next field would be `form1.Main.sfClientInfo.firstname`. I can't figure out how I would change `sfRequestor` to `sfClientInfo` so I can move to the next fields.

Comment: thank you! I was getting hung up on [subform]. I wasn't adding a [] there.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily make this into a simple function:

```
 function validateField(element) {
     if (element.rawValue == null) {
        form1.Main.sfRequest.txtValidate.presence = "visible";
        element.border.edge.color.calue = "255,0,0";
     }
     else {
        form1.Main.sfRequest.txtValidate.presence = "hidden";
        element.border.edge.color.calue = "255,255,255";      
     }
 }
```

And then just call it like so:

```
validateField(form1.Main.sfRequestor.requestNameFirst);
validateField(form1.Main.sfRequestor.requestNameLast);
```

To simplify even further, put all 20 elements in an array and loop

```
var elements = [form1.Main.sfRequestor.requestNameFirst, form1.Main.sfRequestor.requestNameLast, ...];
elements.forEach(function(element) {
    validateField(element);
});
```